# Basic Transition Issues

Tags: philips-hue

I'm trying to write a basic script which uses the remote API to turn on my lights, then transition them to a certain color. The code for doing so using a custom SDK looks something like this:

```
    group.SetState(hue.State{On: true, Bri: 0, Hue: 4000, TransitionTime: 0})
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    group.SetState(hue.State{TransitionTime: 300, Bri: 254, Hue: 11500, Sat: 0})
```

Where each of the `SetState` calls makes a call to the Group command API. Seems simple enough but I'm having a couple of issues:

1. Unless I dim the lights then turn them off first (or call the 'Cinema' formula from Hue Labs), when I call this code the lights come on at whatever brightness they were at before, seemingly ignoring the first `setState` call.
2. The brightness and saturation of the transition are ignored. All it does is transition Hue, though this behavior varies depending on if I include the sleep timer or not.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: It looks like the API isn't even respecting the first statement's brightness setting. If I make the call to set it to 0, nothing happens.

Comment: Can you post any documentation for the SDK?

Comment: @RussJ: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/philips-hue/info

Comment: @RussJ this is the library I am using: https://github.com/amimof/huego

Comment: OH MAN I think I just figured it out. Looking at the library source Brightness and Saturation have `json:"___,omitempty"` on their values, so 0 would be omitted from the request. Testing now to see if I'm right. That burned quite a few hours if that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issues I described were due to `json:"___,omitempty"`being on the brightness, transition, and saturation settings. This means that when they have a value of 0 they are left out when marshalling to json in Go. *facepalm*.

Converting the values to int pointers fixed the issue for me.